¿Cómo puedo ver el código fuente de una libería estándar de python?
Como parte de mi proceso de aprendizaje, me gustaría acceder al código fuente de la librería estándar de Python.
Por ejemplo, me gustaría poder ver como está programado el módulo de "random", o el de "tkinter", para ver cómo es posible hacer el sistema de ventanas, etc.
¿Existe alguna forma de acceder al código fuente?
En la documentación, por ejemplo del módulo random, me dirige al siguiente enlace de github https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Doc/library/random.rst#id3 , sin embargo, lo que visualizo es documentación, mas no código fuente.
Agradecería mucho a quién me pudiese ayudar.

Ese es el código fuente de la documentación, pero en el mismo repositorio tienes también el código fuente de cpython, por ejemplo random: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py. Ten en cuenta que cpython se implementa en C, muchos módulos están implementados completamente o parcialmente en C, en el caso de random: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c, que es el módulo _random que importa random.py. Puedes elegir otra rama para ver el código de tu versión de Python, main actualmente es el futuro Python 3.14

Por otro lado, en la documentacion oficial, en el caso de los módulos de la stdlib, hay un enlace al código fuente justo debajo del título, en https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#module-random encuentras "Código fuente: Lib/random.py" que te lleva al enlace que señalaba arriba.

El enlace que colocas en la pregunta es, efectivamente, a la documentación, sin embargo, si observas el sitio de github, ya estás dentro del repositorio correcto y puedes navegar al código fuente.
Específicamente el fuente de random, que es el que apunta la documentación que refieres está en:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3af7263037de1d0ef63b070fc7bfc2cf042eaebe/Lib/random.py#L336
Ojo, que este enlace es a una versión específica a un commit de la rama de la versión 3.10, que es la que refiere la documentación.
El punto de entrada al repositorio es:
https://github.com/python/cpython/
Si observas la parte superior de esa página, al día de hoy:

Puedes navegar entre el código, la lista de issues, que son los casos (abiertos, cerrados, etc), Pull requests, que son modificaciones realizadas por contribuyentes al código que aún no han sido procesadas, etc.
Si expandes el menú que aparece en la rama, puedes navegar por el código de las distintas ramas que tiene el repositorio.

La página de github es bastante amplia y está fuera del alcance de esta respuesta explicar todo lo que puedes encontrar o hacer en ella.
Este es el link a la rama de la versión 3.13
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.13
En la parte central de la página encontrarás un visor del sistema de carpetas y archivos por el que puedes navegar y, abajo de eso, te mostrará el contenido del readme.md de la carpeta donde te encuentres (si lo hay).
Te invito a visitar la documentacion de github, donde encontrarás mucha más información.

el problema de este tipo de preguntas y respuesta es que si incluyes link en un par de años puede estar obsoleto ...

Claro, la pregunta es dónde está el código fuente el día de la pregunta. No hay forma de saber cuál va a ser el link en el futuro. En SO en inglés, hace unos días actualicé el link de una pregunta que respondí hace 11 años, gracias a un comentario de alguien que comentó que estaba desactualizado.

si y lo mismo pasa con las imagenes que describen una interface ...pasa el tiempo y despues no esta hay lo que buscas

Todo cambia, todo el tiempo. El código y las explicaciones de muchas respuestas también van quedando desactualizadas, dependiendo de qué tanta compatibilidad hacia atrás hay en las nuevas versiones de compiladores, IDE's, bibliotecas, etc. Pienso que no por eso no vamos a dejar de escribir preguntas o respuestas.

Si solo te interesa el código Python puro, puedes también usar el módulo inspect. Por ejemplo si quieres ver el código del módulo random de la biblioteca estándar prueba a usar el siguiente código:
import inspect
import random

print(inspect.getsource(random))

Pero ojo, el módulo inspect, como ya dije, solo puede mostrar el código fuente de los módulos escritos en Python. Si lo intentas con un módulo que esté escrito en C (como varios módulos de la biblioteca estándar y muchos de terceros) recibirás un error porque el código fuente no está disponible en forma de texto de Python.
Puedes verlo haciendo lo mismo con el módulo math. Verás cómo te da el siguiente error:

TypeError: <module 'math' (built-in)> is a built-in module

